# Woocommerce checkout - payment_method was called incorrectly

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment

With Woocommerce, I am using a function to hide payment options when user select a specific shipping:

```
  public function custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
        $chosen_shipping_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

        if ( in_array( 'local_pickup:14', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            unset( $gateways['cod'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:17', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
            unset( $gateways['przelewy24'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:18', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
            unset( $gateways['przelewy24'] );


        endif;
        return $gateways;
    }
```

Add CommentCollapse

Message Input

Jot something down

*bold* *italics* ~strike~ `code` `preformatted` >quote
Search Results

Include:
everything
All
Messages
Files
1 Result

that is working fine but i am getting an error - payment_method was called incorrectly - how can i change this function to call it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have made very small changes in your code and I have tested it in the function.php file of my active child theme. It works without problems:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'custom_available_payment_gateways' );
function custom_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    $chosen_sm = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if ( in_array( 'local_pickup:14', $chosen_sm ) )
    {
        if( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) )
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    } elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:17', $chosen_sm ) || in_array( 'flat_rate:18', $chosen_sm ) )
    {
        if( isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) )
            unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
        if( isset( $available_gateways['przelewy24'] ) )
            unset( $available_gateways['przelewy24'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

So for a plugin the hook part will be slightly different (and located in the `init()` function):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', array($this, 'custom_available_payment_gateways') );
public function custom_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    $chosen_sm = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if ( in_array( 'local_pickup:14', $chosen_sm ) )
    {
        if( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) )
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    } elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:17', $chosen_sm ) || in_array( 'flat_rate:18', $chosen_sm ) )
    {
        if( isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) )
            unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
        if( isset( $available_gateways['przelewy24'] ) )
            unset( $available_gateways['przelewy24'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

It should work.